# Update mono on opensuse 13.2

Tags: mono, opensuse

I am wondering if anyone can show me where to find or help me
how to update mono 3.8 on opensuse 13.2.
I want to update it to new version, because this one
have too many bugs and dont run goo with my aplications
on my server.

Answer (score 0):

The Mono project provides [one-click](http://www.opensuse-guide.org/installpackage.php) installs for openSUSE, currently versions up to 4.0.4.1-0 are available.

> openSUSE and SLES
>
> You can install using SUSE One-Click files (see below for
>   descriptions):
>
> - [mono-devel](http://download.mono-project.com/repo/mono-devel.ymp)
> - [mono-complete](http://download.mono-project.com/repo/mono-complete.ymp)
> - [referenceassemblies-pcl](http://download.mono-project.com/repo/referenceassemblies-pcl.ymp)

Ref: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#opensuse-and-sles

Comment: Thank you for this great tips, but i am runing minimal server so i run with terminal so i need commands. I was trying with .rpm files and didnt have luck to update it.

Comment: You should be able to use `/sbin/OCICLI` with those ymp urls to install via the CLI...

Comment: Hm i get this error message:  bash: /sbin/OCICLI: No such file or directory

Comment: hmmm... it has been while since I've been on an opensuse box.... https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:One_click_install#Can_I_Install_One_Click_Install_Links_from_the_command_line.3F